# Tomcat Logging Exceptions - Uncaught Exception Handler

Tags: jsf, tomcat, logging, jsf-2, tomcat7

When running in Tomcat I can't see uncaught Facelet Runtime Exceptions being output in the catalina.out or localhost log files.

When running in Jetty I get the following:

```
2014-05-24 11:15:44.804:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/delivery

javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /delivery.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 47] The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:130)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:495)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$200(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:92)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:146)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:246)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:241)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:575)
```

Comment: I think that tomcat is not logging uncaught exceptions..I've checked the localhost file and this is empty as well

Comment: I've also checked that printing to stdout and stderr outputs into catalina.out

Comment: What kind of logger does your app use?